# How to customise a string based on if user got a new record?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've almost finished my first project on a multiplication test. I want to have a message at the end of my print function that says something like "You got a score of 10 out of 13 in 55 seconds"

This is what the actual code looks like:
`print("\u001b[0m You got a score of ", rg2, score, "out of 13 ",  "\u001b[0m in " + rg, brackets.format(format), "\u001b[0m seconds!")`

I want to add a message at the end that will tell you if you got a new record in any of these 3 categories:

1. Score Record for a specific times table
2. Time Record for all times tables
3. Time Record for a specific times table

For Example: "New Score Record for the Times Table 8x".

The way I've done this is:

1. Make the user input their name.
2. Check if they have played before with:

   ```
   if not os.path.exists('{}.txt'.format(username)):  
       with open('{}.txt'.format(username), 'w') as f:
   ```
3. Write all the score records into the txt file created:  `f.write('61\n0\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61')`
   I don't know why I chose 61
4. When the questions are done; check if the score or time is lower than the line it is assigned in the txt file.
5. If it is; make a variable called ntr(meaning "new time record")
6. Then checking if it exists with:

   ```
   #TTT|TF
   if 'ntr' in locals():
     nr = ntr
     if 'nsr' in locals():
       nr = '\u001b[34;1m New Time and Score Record!'
       if 'nttr' in locals():
         nr = 'New Time, Score and Times Table Time Record for {}x!'.format(tt)
         if 'nttsr' in locals():

   #TTF|TF
   if 'ntr' in locals():
     if not 'nsr' in locals():
       if 'nttr' in locals():
         nr = '\u001b[34;1m New Time and Times Table Time Record for {}x!'.format(tt)
         if 'nttsr' in locals():




   #TFT|TF
   if 'ntr' in locals():
     if not 'nsr' in locals():
       if 'nttr' in locals():
         nr = '\u001b[34;1m New Time and Times Table Time Record for {}x!'.format(tt)
         if 'nttsr' in locals():

   #TFF|TF      
   if 'ntr' in locals():
     if not 'nsr' in locals():
       if not 'nttr' in locals():
         nr = 
         if 'nttsr' in locals():

   #FFF|TF
   if not 'ntr' in locals():
     if not 'nsr' in locals():
       if not 'nttr' in locals():
         if 'nttsr' in locals():

   #FFT|TF
   if not 'ntr' in locals():
     if not 'nsr' in locals():
       if 'nttr' in locals():
         if 'nttsr' in locals():

   #FTF|TF
   if not 'ntr' in locals():
     if 'nsr' in locals():
       if not 'nttr' in locals():
         if 'nttsr' in locals():
           nr = '\u001b[34;1m New Score Record and Score Record for {}x'.format(tt)

   #FTT|TF
   if not 'ntr' in locals():
     if 'nsr' in locals():
       if 'nttr' in locals():
         nr = '\u001b[34;1m New Score and Times Table Time Record for {}x!'.format(tt)
         if 'nttsr' in locals():

   if not 'nr' in locals():
     nr = ""
   ```

   The "T's and F's are representing True and false just to help me and I also haven't finished the last one that goes: `if 'nttsr' in locals():`

Here is my full code:

```
from random import sample
import time
import math
import os


username = str(input("What is your first name? "))

if not os.path.exists('{}.txt'.format(username)):
  with open('{}.txt'.format(username), 'w') as f:
    f.write('61\n0\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61\n61')
    
with open('{}.txt'.format(username), 'r') as f:
  content = f.readlines()
  
tt = int(input("Enter a times table: "))

time_record = float(content[0])
score_record = int(content[1])
N = tt+2
time_recordN = float(content[N])
S = tt+15
score_recordN = int(content[S])


score = 0
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
numberList = sample(list, k=13)
i = 0

while i < 13:

  number = numberList[i]

  if i == 0:
    start_time = time.time()
  
  answer = input("{} x {} = ".format(number,tt))
    
  if int(answer) == number* tt:
    print("\u001b[32;1m" + "Correct!" + "\u001b[0m")
    print()
    score = score+ 1

  else:
    print("\u001b[31;1m" + "Incorrect")
    print("\u001b[34;1m", (number * tt))
    print()
  
  i += 1
  
#finish timer, end of random loop, start of def
end_time = time.time()
time_lapsed = end_time - start_time

seconds = time_lapsed
minutes = seconds // 60
seconds = seconds % 60
hours = minutes // 60
minutes = minutes % 60

seconds = round(seconds, 2)
minutes = math.trunc(minutes)
hours = math.trunc(hours)


if time_lapsed < time_recordN:
  time_recordN = time_lapsed
  time_recordN = str(time_recordN)
  content[N] = '{}\n'.format(time_recordN)
  nttr = '\u001b[34;1m New Time Record for {}x!'.format(tt)

if score < score_recordN:
  score_recordN = score
  score_recordN = str(score_recordN)
  content[S] = '{}\n'.format(score_recordN)
  nttsr = '\u001b[34;1m New Score Record for {}!'.format(tt)
  
if time_lapsed < time_record:
  rg = "\u001b[32;1m"
  ntr = '\u001b[34;1m New Time Record!'
  time_record = time_lapsed
if time_lapsed < 60:
  brackets = "{}"
  format = seconds
else:
  if time_lapsed < 3600:
    brackets = "{} {}"
    format = minutes, seconds
  else:
    brackets = "{} {} {}"
    format = hours, minutes, seconds

if time_lapsed > time_record:
  rg = "\u001b[31;1m"
  
time_record = str(time_record)
content[0] = '{}\n'.format(time_record)

if score > score_record:
  rg2 = "\u001b[32;1m"
  nsr = '\u001b[34;1m New Score Record!'
  score_record = score
  score_record = str(score_record)
  content[1] = '{}\n'.format(score_record)

else:
  rg2 = "\u001b[31;1m"

content = content
with open('{}.txt'.format(username), 'w') as f:
  f.writelines(content)

#TTT|TF
if 'ntr' in locals():
  nr = ntr
  if 'nsr' in locals():
    nr = '\u001b[34;1m New Time and Score Record!'
    if 'nttr' in locals():
      nr = 'New Time, Score and Times Table Time Record for {}x!'.format(tt)
      if 'nttsr' in locals():
      
#TTF|TF
if 'ntr' in locals():
  if not 'nsr' in locals():
    if 'nttr' in locals():
      nr = '\u001b[34;1m New Time and Times Table Time Record for {}x!'.format(tt)
      if 'nttsr' in locals():
      
#TFT|TF
if 'ntr' in locals():
  if not 'nsr' in locals():
    if 'nttr' in locals():
      nr = '\u001b[34;1m New Time and Times Table Time Record for {}x!'.format(tt)
      if 'nttsr' in locals():
      
#TFF|TF      
if 'ntr' in locals():
  if not 'nsr' in locals():
    if not 'nttr' in locals():
      nr = 
      if 'nttsr' in locals():

#FFF|TF
if not 'ntr' in locals():
  if not 'nsr' in locals():
    if not 'nttr' in locals():
      if 'nttsr' in locals():

#FFT|TF
if not 'ntr' in locals():
  if not 'nsr' in locals():
    if 'nttr' in locals():
      if 'nttsr' in locals():

#FTF|TF
if not 'ntr' in locals():
  if 'nsr' in locals():
    if not 'nttr' in locals():
      if 'nttsr' in locals():
        nr = '\u001b[34;1m New Score Record and Score Record for {}x'.format(tt)

#FTT|TF
if not 'ntr' in locals():
  if 'nsr' in locals():
    if 'nttr' in locals():
      nr = '\u001b[34;1m New Score and Times Table Time Record for {}x!'.format(tt)
      if 'nttsr' in locals():

if not 'nr' in locals():
  nr = ""

print("\u001b[0m You got a score of", rg2, score, "out of 13",  "\u001b[0m in" + rg, brackets.format(format), "\u001b[0m seconds!", nr)
```

I would love any help :D

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question would be better if you narrowed it down a bit. Maybe share a small section of the code and what you want it to do, or at least put this at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've come up with, I think it should satisfy your needs. Also you seem to use extensively the ANSI reset color character `\u001b[0m`, are you sure you really need it?

```py
from random import sample
import time
import os

username = input("usr: ")
score_file = "{}.txt".format(username)

DEFAULT_TIME = 61
DEFAULT_SCORE = 0

# We will store the overall time record first
# Then the time and score record for all times tables
# We don't create the lines for these times tables as we want to be able to play 
# any one of them
if not os.path.exists(score_file):
    with open(score_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write("{}".format(DEFAULT_TIME))
with open(score_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    content = f.read().split("\n")

# Get all played times tables
# We put them in a dictionary that stores the global record and the time/score record 
# for all played times tables
records = {
    "global": DEFAULT_TIME,
    "tt": {}
}
for line in content:
    if "\t" not in line:
        records["global"] = float(line)
    else:
        line = line.split("\t")
        records["tt"][int(line[0])] = [float(line[1]), int(line[2])]

# Get the desired times table and initialize the dictionary entry 
# if necessary
tt = int(input("Enter a times table: "))
if tt not in records["tt"]:
    records["tt"][tt] = []
    records["tt"][tt].append(DEFAULT_TIME)
    records["tt"][tt].append(DEFAULT_SCORE)

# Get best times and scores
best_time = records["global"]
best_time_tt = records["tt"][tt][0]
best_score_tt = records["tt"][tt][1]

# Do the test
score = 0
list_questions = [x for x in range(13)]
number_list = sample(list_questions, k=2)

start = time.time()
for number in number_list:
    answer = input("{} x {} = ".format(number, tt))
    if int(answer) == number*tt:
        print("Correct!")
        score += 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect: {}".format(number*tt))
end = time.time()

run_time = round((end-start), 2)

# Factorized the message writing a bit, allow to not have this long ifs sequence
message = ""
if run_time < best_time:
    message += "Global time record, Time record"
    records["global"] = run_time
    records["tt"][tt][0] = run_time
elif run_time < best_time_tt:
    message += "Time record"
    records["tt"][tt][0] = run_time
if score > best_score_tt:
    if message != "":
        message += " and "
    message += "Score record"
    records["tt"][tt][1] = score
if message != "":
    print(message + "!!")
else:
    print("No record achieved now")

# Write the records dictionary into the user file
with open(score_file, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(str(records["global"]) + "\n")
    for i,key in enumerate(records["tt"]):
        f.write("{}\t{}\t{}".format(key, records["tt"][key][0], records["tt"][key][1]))
        if i != len(records["tt"])-1:
            f.write("\n")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't yet understand for loops that well, but I modified it a little bit and it works perfectly!

Comment: Here `content` is a list of lines (from the `split("\n")` operation). In python, one of the syntax of the `for` loop is this one. `line` will successively take each value of `content` in the order they are in the list.

Additionally, if the issue you had is solved, could you accept the answer?